# Update FutureBuilder ListView locally

Tags: flutter

I'm getting data from an API using **FutureBuilder** which return a list which is drawn in a **ListView.builder**

I then have a **TextField** I use to search en filter entites. How can I access the data retrived by the future? Or should I store them locally in the start by override **initState**? I also want to update the list by my searchfilter without doing another GET to the API which occurs if i do a **setState()**.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
          )),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Search", prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            controller: searchField,
            onChanged: (value) {
              filterSearchResults(value.toLowerCase());
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _getCustomers(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                            elevation: 5,
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: const Icon(
                                Icons.account_circle,
                                size: 45,
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                  "${snapshot.data[index].firstName} ${snapshot.data[index].lastName}"),
                              subtitle:
                                  Text("${snapshot.data[index].socialNumber}"),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => CustomerPage(
                                            customer: snapshot.data[index])));
                              },
                            ));
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  //handle this
                  return null;
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is stored in a list, and then modifed due to the queryString the solutions was to only call getCustomers at init:

```
  Future<List<Customer>> getCustomers;

  @override
  void initState() {
      getCustomers = _getCustomers();
      super.initState();
  }

  ...
  child: FutureBuilder(
      future: getCustomers,
  ...
```

And then save the list in a local object as well and use that after

> setState(() { });

which can be done using an additional if-statement:

```
      if (items.length > 0) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                ....
            });
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
          ConnectionState.done) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    ....
                });
```

where items is the local list which is used except for first time when the list from the API is used and then stored locally.

Comment: hey, can you provide please more information about the solution ?? the items element, how do you fill up ?